# useCallback not render and use the old value

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, file-upload, react-redux

I have useCallback function, I use it to track files that the user uploads, and update the file data and file status(uploading, deleting, success or notExtension) in redux .

if the user upload or deleting file, the redux is updated by functions external to the component, but if he uploads file with wrong extension, the redux is update in the componnent.

the problem is that when the user upload file, and then change it to file with wrong extension, the status updating in redux changing but all other data remains and is not deleted. to example, I steel see the old file name.

here the useCallback function:

```
const onDrop= useCallback(
  async (acceptedFiles)=>{
      const file = acceptedFiles[0];
      //sending to delete the file without updating the user
      await deleteFile(false);
      updateFileStatus(UploadStatus.UPLOADING);
      if(file){
        await onLoad(file);
      }
      else{
        updateFileStatus(UploadStatus.INCORRECT_FILE_EXTENSION);
      }
  },
  [onLoad,deleteFile, updateFileStatus, fileData]
)
```

here the updateFileStatus function:

```
const updateFileStatus = (fileStatus:FileStatus) =>{
   dispath( 
       updateFields( fileType,{
         ...fileData //use selector which contains all the information about the file
         fileStatus
       })
    );
};
```

what I try?

- to change the useCallbeck dependencies , It didn't help
- Ito print alot console.log to understand the process , The conclusion I reached is that the delete     works as it should and changes the redux, but in the usecallback the old information is saved and when I update the new status in INCORRECT_FILE_EXTENSION , it takes the old data and updates it as well.
- I try to add async await to other function in the process,To check if there is a synchronization problem, which may take time for the process. It didn't help.

If you have any idea I would really appreciate it

This is almost the first time I am writing a question here, if there is any information missing or if something is not clear I would be happy to complete the missing information

Comment: Could you share the reducer code fired when updateFields is dispacthed

Answer (score 0):

Firstly if you're having an issue with `useCallback` I'd always advise removing the `useCallback` wrapper. If this fixes the issue, then at least we know there's a problem in the usage of `useCallback`, likely the dependency array. Incidentally, your dependency array contains `fileData` which is unnecessary.

Secondly, is this code copied and pasted, or retyped? There is a typo in `dispath` (should be `dispatch`) but perhaps this is only present in the question. If not a typo in the question, this would be causing you some problems in your code.